# Identifying bridge accessory in HomeKit

Tags: ios, swift, homekit, ios-homekit

How can I identify an `HMAccessory` as a bridge? Perhaps I have missed something but I cannot seem to find any `HMServiceType` or `HMCharacteristicType` that corresponds to a bridge. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `category: HMAccessoryCategoryType` property on `HMAccessory` where HMAccessoryCategoryTypeBridge represents bridge apparently. The online docs seem to be missing a lot of new properties and functions introduced in iOS9.
One can also use `uniqueIdentifiersForBridgedAccessories: [NSUUID]?` on HMAccessory which returns non-nil if the accessory is a bridge

Answer (score 0):

You can find out if an accessory is a bridge using the following code when inspecting a specific accessory:

```
if accessory.category.categoryType == HMAccessoryCategoryTypeBridge {
  print("I'M A BRIDGE")
}
```